# How to get background image in tkinter to show above all labels except text on it

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have created a weather GUI application which is working well
Here is the code:
https://github.com/ApurvaLawate/Weather/blob/master/weatherApp.py

I want to add one last functionality. The app recieves data in JSON format which has one variable called data['weather']['main'] which can have 8 values like Rain,Thunderstorm,Drizzle, etc. I want to change background of this App to Drizzle.jpg if the data['weather']['main'] == Drizzle which can be done but before that the image must be showing on entire background and not just behind labels. Here is the output for reference:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13SZQK9i1uXd7Qq4p-3KMTMZnhSFJJtXM/view?usp=sharing

I have also noticed that changing width of labels changes their position and the image shows up on more area. So the problem is more like making labels transparent except for the text. Please share any help.

Comment: You can use `Canvas` to hold the background image (using `Canvas.create_image()`), entries and buttons (using `Canvas.create_window()`).  Then use `Canvas.create_text()` to show the weather information.

Comment: But I guess doing this will remove the functionality of Label.config(). As getWeather() function updates the default label values. I am really confused how to do it. can we have labels with canvas?

Comment: You can use `Canvas.create_text()` to create the required weather information first, then use `Canvas.itemconfigure()` to update the text.

Comment: oh I see. so to make sure what I need to do is remove labels and add canvas. right?

Comment: As I said, the background image, entry and button should be put inside the canvas as well.

Comment: Your github link is broken i suppose